# Matlab: Replace string with regexprep, by inserting parts of the current match

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string of the format:

`a = '{header:Header { length: 3, number: two, month: april }, holiday : summerholiday {holiday:france}}'`

On this string I want to use the `jsondecode` function of Matlab, so I need the string to be in the following format:

`a_desired = '{"header": {"length":"3", "number":"two", "month":"april"}, "holiday": {"holiday" : "france"}}'`

I need to remove every word in the string, that is followed by `: word {`  (as Header and summerholiday).

My idea:

```
a = '{header:Header {length:3, number:two, month:april}, holiday : summerholiday: {holiday : france}}';
exp = '\w*:\w* {';
str_json = regexprep(a, exp, '$&' ); 
// nothing changes, because I insert the same string I want to replace
```

How can I insert only parts of the current regular expression instead of inserting the hole portion of the input text that is currently a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output in two steps.

**1. Remove unwanted words from string.**

`a_desired = regexprep(a,'(:)\s?[a-zA-Z]*\s*({)','$1 $2')`

The regular expression explained:

- `(:)` Match a semi colon and capture it.
- `\s?[a-zA-Z]*` Match a whitespace optionally, followed by a word.
- `\s*` Match any whitespace
- `({)` Match a opening bracket and capture it in the second group.

The matched patterns are replaced by `$1`, the first captured group, whitespace, and `$2`, the second captured group.

**2. Wrap every word in double quotes.**

`a_desired = regexprep(a_desired,'(\w*)','"$1"')`

- `(\w*)` Match any word and capture it.

The matched patterns are replaced by the captured group, $1, wrapped inside double quotes characters.

The final output:

`a_desired = '{"header": {"length":"3", "number":"two", "month":"april"}, "holiday": {"holiday" : "france"}}'`

Comment: Thanks very much!
Is it possible to match a word followed by a unknown number of words until the next bracket {? Is there an easier way as:
match = regexp(a, '\w* (\w*?)(\s?)(\w*?)(\s?)(\w*?")(\s?){')

Comment: Sorry, this is my last question on this topic:
As an extension to my question 1 hour ago: if I want to find a match with the hole content between the string "description" and a bracket {, but in between these two tokens, there are not only unknown words, but also signs as /;.(, is there a solution using regexp anyway?

Comment: No worries. Can you share expected input and output for this case? A lot easier to see an example of what you mean :).

Comment: This is my input:
`a = testphase:{comand:{inputcheck:" ", num: 2000, details: start phase reached, initial  }}`
or
`b = testphase:{comand:{inputcheck:" ", num: 2000, details: start phase reached ( loading packages)  }}`

`a_desired = "testphase":{"comand":{"inputcheck":" ", "num": "2000", "details": "start phase reached, initial"  }}`

`b:desired = "testphase":{"comand":{"inputcheck":" ", "num": "2000", "details": "start phase reached ( loading packages)"  }}`

I don't reach to group the content after "details" correctly, to set the "" at the end as wished.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Miri try `regexprep(a,'(\w*(?=\S)|((\w*\s*[,()]?)*(?=\s})))','"$1"')` for both `a_desired` and `b_desired` :)